# Rep changes from Meta don't appear in iOS app?

Tags: bug, ios-app, achievements-dialog

Comments on my Meta SO posts are showing up in the iOS app:

[image: comments]

But this comment was on a post I recently made which has (as of writing) 5 upvotes. I wasn't notified of those votes:

[image: reputation changes]

Shouldn't the votes / rep changes appear here?

Answer (score 2):

Voting works different on meta-sites. You don't gain (or lose) reputation from votes. Therefore, they don't appear on the achievement list (neither on the website nor in the app).

Meta StackExchange is the only exception - voting works there as on all the main sites.

Comment: Oh. Silly me. Where's the official documentation of this? Somewhere in the help center I missed?

Comment: @jtbandes The dupe question includes the documentation on MSO.