# Newly posted question content appears in the wrong place

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, posting

Something has gone horribly wrong.

Here's what I did:

1. Start writing a new question in the iOS app.
2. Type a title, then tap one of the suggested/related questions.
3. Tap a link to the question which it was marked as a duplicate of. (I think through 2 levels of duplicates.)
4. Tap the blue bubble to go back to the question I was editing.
5. Finish and submit my question.

Then this is what I saw:

[image: bork bork bork]

That's [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277938/131139) above, but the answer below was an answer on one of the related questions I'd looked at. Yikes!

Comment: 'Asked: 12 secs ago' - 'Answered: December '15'..............what a stuff up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.6.

The suggested question mechanism is jury-rigged on top of the post drafting mechanism which is entangled with the question editor delegate, so when the question editor navigates to a suggested question it attached the question as its editing delegate.  We had one method, `questionEditorViewController(_:,didPostQuestionWithResponse:)` that different delegates handled differently, and the question view controller simply replaced the displayed question with the new one because it assumed it was an edit.

Now the question editor still attached the delegate for drafting purposes but when it submits a new question or requests a suggested question, it universally does this as a notification to the root view controller.  It was already doing this in some circumstances and this is the standard behavior used by the hot network question today extension, Spotlight, the browser top bar, etc, so it should be more reliable and reduce the number of inconsistencies we have.

I'm hoping to significantly improve drafting by the final App Store release so we can get rid of delegate reassignment altogether.