# Draft doesn't remember it was an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

Steps:

1. Begin editing a post
2. Tap Back to hide the draft (blue bubble appears)
3. Go back to the feed (blue bubble no longer visible)
4. Open sidebar and tap to ask a new question
5. Tap dialog to resume editing the draft
6. Submit the draft.

Expected: it's submitted as an edit of the post I originally started editing.

Actual: I get an error dialog preventing me from submitting the question because it's a duplicate of another (namely the original I was trying to edit).

Comment: That is weird. According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220797/152859), there shouldn't be draft for edits to begin with.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing.  Are there other steps involved?  New questions drafts are different from edit drafts.  (Internally `question-draft` vs `edit-for-post-{id}-draft`).  When I get to step 5 I get the draft of the last question I started, not the last question I was editing.

Comment: Not sure what other steps might have been involved. I can try doing more stuff to reproduce, but it might be easier for you to just read the code and figure out if there are any ways for the draft to get associated as a question draft... :/

Comment: I definitely did get an error dialog telling me I couldn't submit because it was an exact duplicate, so there was something that went wrong, but perhaps another step was involved that I've since forgotten...

Comment: @jtbandes Brian probably missed your comments. To notify users when replying in comments, use `@` followed by the user name.

Comment: OK, thanks. IME notification happens automatically, but maybe that's only when the conversation is between exactly 2 people. Hi @BrianNickel ^

Comment: Were you trying to edit a question you had just created?  I've found a probable scenario for this issue and I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.6.

The source of this bug can actually be seen in [your other bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277940/newly-posted-question-content-appears-in-the-wrong-place):

> [image: Draft widget on newly posted questions]

When you posted the new question, the draft indicator for it should have gone away.  Instead it retained the editor you used to submit the question so when you tapped on the button it brought back the old question causing the new question draft to be saved again.  Incidentally, you couldn't have submitted from that editor so you really did have to exit out and go to start a new question to get the full effect.

There are two fixes:

- The first fix was actually fixing the other bug so you didn't end up just being on the same question.
- The second was to remove any similar questions that you viewed from the navigation stack on submission.  That way you don't post a question, go back one, tap the draft indicator and get your question draft saved again.

  Already when you go from the first similar question to the second, we remove the first from the stack so only one question has a draft indicator and you don't end up with a deep stack of similar questions.  I just extended that to drop the similar question when showing the new question as well.